# Change date format of a stored date value in a database?

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

I have a database which stores value in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format.

When I retrieve values, I want them to be displayed in `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm AM/PM` format. I cannot change the way I store them in the first place.

I am using a Cursor to get results from the database and then add them to a list, which is then used by listadapter to populate the listview.

Since Cursor returns a string how can I change the format of the returned value?

Comment: Check this [SimpleDateFormat example](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-get-current-date-and-time-in-different-format/), understand it and try it out for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with the pattern like "`dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm a`".

```
Date mDate= new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm a");
System.out.println(mDateFormat.format(mDate));
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't save date to database in any specific formats. you should save date in form of milliseconds and then use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to change it to any required format.

Comment: Okay, I did as you said but since I am using Cursor when displaying results, the cursor returns date as a string, which is creating an error when I try to use it with SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: typecast it to Long. it would work. Long.parseLong(String string)

Answer (score 2):

You will want to do something like this:

```
//Retrieve date from database
SimpleDateFormat origFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String stringDateFromDB = getDateFromDatabase();

//Store it as a date object
Date date = origFormat.parse(stringDateFromDB);

//Output it as a string that uses the new format
SimpleDateFormat newFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm AM/PM");
String desiredDateFormat = newFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

try as given below

```
Date c_date;
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm a");
c_date=(Date)outputFormat.parse(Date_Database);
```

where

```
Date_Database= your date which is in String format which u have retraived from database
```